# Jinja2 mark specific HTML tag as safe

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I'm aware of both safe and escape filters in jinja, but I couldn't find a solution for my problem.

I have the following string :

```
mystring = """<script>alert('I'm unsafe')</script>

I just entered a new line


Two new lines now!"""
```

I want to use it in a `<p>` tag showing the newlines properly :

```
<p>{{mystring | replace('\n', '<br>')}}</p>
```

This doesn't work as Jinja2 automatically escapes HTML tags, but if I do :

```
<p>{{mystring | replace('\n', '<br>') | safe }}</p>
```

It will then be unsafe.

What I have tried is :

```
<p>{{mystring | escape | replace('\n', '<br>') | safe }}</p>
```

But the above doesn't work, the `<br>`s are still escaped for some reason

How can I have the `<br>` tags not be escaped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to mark `<br>` tag as safe, the solution is to use a **custom filter** as described [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#custom-filters)

> Here a small example filter that breaks a text into HTML line breaks and paragraphs and marks the return value as safe HTML string if autoescaping is enabled:

with some customization, you can adapt the logic to your case:

create `filters.py` (to make the application modular)

```
import re
from jinja2 import evalcontextfilter, Markup, escape

_paragraph_re = re.compile(r'(\n)')

@evalcontextfilter
def nl2br(eval_ctx, value):

    result = ''.join('%s' % p.replace('\n', Markup('<br>'))
        for p in _paragraph_re.split(escape(value)))

    if eval_ctx.autoescape:
        result = Markup(result)

    return result
```

and then in `app.py`

```
from flask import Flask

from .filters import nl2br

app = Flask(__name__)
[..]
app.jinja_env.filters['nl2br'] = nl2br
```

and then in you template

```
<p>{{ mystring | nl2br }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading @cizario's answer, I found the following solution not involving custom filters:

`<p>{{mystring | replace('\n', '<br>' | safe) }}</p>`

The problem highlighted by the question is that `replace` produces unsafe strings that will be escaped afterward.
By telling to the template engine that our `'<br>'` strings are safe, we avoid that it escapes the line breaks produced by the `replace` filter.